# IOS: suggestions for change view

Tags: ios, xcode, view

In weather app (in basilar iPhone app) there is a button with an "i" for info; when you press this "i" there is a interesting effect to change view; what's the name of this effect? I want replay it in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a modal transition style between `UIViewController`s and not `UIView`s.

In the example you described UIViewController being loaded is a presented in a modal way and the transition style is set to `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`

```
UIViewController *controllerToBeLoaded = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presenteModalViewController:controllerToBeLoaded animated:YES];
```

Where `self` is also a `UIViewController`